# Is this a bug in the pfb file or a bug in metapost's "glyph"?

Tags: fonts, metapost

I've only recently started [playing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129274/showcase-of-optical-illusions-made-with-tex-latex-luatex-context/151762#151762) with metapost's "glyph".  I've discovered (MWE below) an anomaly with the paths in serifs for the cm font set from these experiments.

Starting point: it seems that metapost gets the glyphs from the .pfb file for the font (e.g. `.../texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb`).

My question is which of the following is causing the anomalies, so I can figure out whether a bug report is warranted and who to send it to...

1. There is a bug in the .pfb file.  Since it is a path that *almost* doubles back on itself, which may not result in any pixels being filled, so no-one has noticed.
2. I am wrong about where metapost gets the glyphs from, and the bug is wherever that is.
3. There is a bug in the glyph code in metapost.
4. Something else.

Things I have done:

1. Checked that other programs that use these fonts use the same .pfb file (yes AFAICT for `pdflatex` and for `latex|dvips|pstopdf`) and looked at greatly magnified characters in the pdf output of these - no luck.
2. Looked for other tools to extract glyphs from a .pfb - can't find any.  (Tips on this would be nice)
3. Checked the strokes in `cmr.mf` (actually `cmbase.mf`) - Knuth's serifs are a separate stroke to the rest of the letter, so no clue there.
4. Looked up the various tools that may have been used to produce these type1 fonts (MFTOEPS etc) from Knuth's source, but decided that is beyond my expertise.
5. Looked on texexchange and further afield
6. Checked version info (MetaPost=v1.504, cmr10.pfb=v003.002) and checked the changelog for more recent metapost

My MWE shows the boundary of the glyph overshoots, then doubles back in the serif, and a small amount extra area within the glyph for "I" in `cmr10`.  Due to the geometry of the serifs in `cmti10` there is still the overshoot but no extra area.  It also shows up in some other fonts (bold, slant) in the cm font set, and in serifs in both uppercase and lowercase.

```
picture pic[];
path p[];
pair d;

pic0=btex  I\it I etex; % <---- the text to be analysed
_i:=1;
for $ within pic0:
    p[_i]=pathpart glyph (textpart $) of (fontpart $) scaled 1/100 shifted llcorner $ scaled 20;
    _i:=_i+1;
endfor

beginfig(1)
for i = 1 upto 20:
    if known p[i]:
        fill p[i] withcolor (.8,.8,.9);
        for j = 0 upto (length(p[i])-1):
            draw point j of p[i]--postcontrol j of p[i] dashed withdots scaled 1/4;
            draw point j+1 of p[i]--precontrol j+1 of p[i] dashed withdots scaled 1/4;
            fill fullcircle scaled 0.5mm shifted point j of (p[i]);
            d:=direction j of p[i];
            if abs(d)=0: d:=point j+4 of p[i] - point j-4 of p[i]; fi
            a:= if abs(d)=0: 0 else: angle(d) fi;
            draw thelabel.lft(decimal j infont "cmbx5",(0,0))
                rotated (a+90)
                shifted (point j of (p[i] )) withcolor blue;
        endfor
        draw p[i] withpen pencircle scaled 0.1;
    fi
endfor
endfig;

bye
```

[image]

Comment: The Type1 version for the CM fonts has been produced several years ago by BlueSky Research; I don't know what they used, but surely it predates `mftoeps`.

Comment: Looking at my local copy of CMTI10.pfb with Fontlab's Typetool shows no such horrid jags in the capital I, even though I get the same results as you from Metapost.  This suggests the problem is with extracting the pic elements in mpost.

Comment: If you are on a Mac or using GNU/Linux, FontForge may be helpful for examining the glyphs and can provide a lot of information about fonts in general.

Comment: Just to confirm: the problem does not appear when I zoom in on the I in /usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb in FontForge, either.

Comment: Mmm so it looks like the .pfb is OK.  If it is metapost doing this then it is a bit strange - the stray point in the path is centred on the foot of the vertical.  Metapost is unlikely to be smart enough to figure this point out for itself.  More likely that point is there in the font file but not as a point on the path, and that metapost is misinterpreting it.  On page 76 of Adobe's [T1_SPEC.PDF](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/T1_SPEC.PDF) is a picture similar to the above, associated with the "flex" feature of T1 fonts, so this is probably the source of the error.

Comment: Two different parts of metapost are involved here. If you do something simple like `draw "I" infont "cmti12" scaled 20` you won't see the jag.  But if you do `draw pathpart glyph "I" of "cmti12" scaled 0.5` the jag is very obvious.  Apparently the implementation of `glyph` ignores the flex feature. I'm not good enough at reading the web2c source to be sure but the fault appears to be in the `mp_gr_unexport` function (which has become `mp_gr_import` in v1.803) in `mp.w`.

Comment: PS if you want to see the lowest level of detail in a T1 font, the `t1utils` package is very handy.  It includes a program called `t1disasm` that extracts all the individual path commands to a simple PS text format.  On a mac with homebrew, try `brew install t1utils`.

Comment: Yes, this mirrors my understanding so far.  The `infont` operator just _uses_ the font (possibly embedded in the eps file, depending on `prologues`) which is then interpreted by a postscript interpreter further down the toolchain.  So MP is really only accessing font metric info, just like TeX does.  OTOH `glyph` digs deeper, using cut-down PS interpreter.  I'll play around with `t1utils` (also on fink, FWIW) but it looks like I'll be dropping a bug report on the metaposters.   I'll leave the question going here for a day or two, hoping for passing font guru!  Then I'll summarise as an answer.

Comment: Andrew, @Thruston: more than a day or two has passed... ;-) If you think they constitute an answer, would one of you like to convert the information in the comments here to an answer?

Comment: @Thruston - thanks for following this all up.  All looks good.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been fixed in `mpost` version 1.999.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue appears to be related to the use of `pathpart` on the picture returned by `glyph`.  Consider the following program:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "glyph%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
  picture a;
  a = glyph "I" of "cmti12";
  draw a withcolor .9 white;
  draw pathpart a withcolor red;
endfig;
end.
```

which produces the picture below.  You can see the jags on the dished serifs clearly (in red) but notice that there are no jags in the grey part.

The `glyph` operator returns a picture of the given character in the given font.  If I just `draw` that picture then the outline looks correct (the grey part of the image).  But if I draw the path returned by `pathpart` then we get the extra jags on the dishes.

This shows that there is no fault in the font file, but rather that there is an issue with `pathpart` when applied to the picture returned by `glyph`.  I've raised an issue with the MP development team -> 
http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=935

**Update**: As of May 15, 2015 this bug is now fixed.

[image]

Here's the output using a newly compiled `mpost` version 1.999:

[image]