# How to change glyph in cmcbxti10 Type1 font?

Tags: fonts, metapost

Glyph 111 of Type1 font cmcbxti10 has some protrusions on top and on bottom.
Consider the following MetaPost file:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "glyph%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
  picture a;
  a = glyph "afii10026" of "cmcbxti10";
  draw a withcolor .9 white;
  draw pathpart a withcolor red;
endfig;
beginfig(2);
  picture a;
  a = glyph "afii10027" of "cmcbxti10";
  draw a withcolor .9 white;
  draw pathpart a withcolor red;
endfig;
end.
```

How to make glyph1.eps look like glyph2.eps without the accent?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried looking at the font with a high resolution bitmap produced from the Metafont sources and the bump is there, so it is a bug in the Metafont code. Here's [the picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkf2D.png) produced with mode `supre` at 2400dpi.

Comment: @egreg: is there an easy way to remove these bumps by editing post script code using t1disasm/t1asm?

Comment: I don't know; you should ask the developers to fix the sources and rerun the Type1 conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151801/is-this-a-bug-in-the-pfb-file-or-a-bug-in-metaposts-glyph

Comment: There was a bug in MP's handling of "flex" constructions often used in serifs, that was fairly recently fixed and may not be in your version of `mpost`.  See my answer to the question linked in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Thruston: no, it is not mpost bug, check for example with `\font\x=cmcbxti10 at 300pt\x\char'151\bye`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed by using the following patch with `t1disasm`/`t1asm`:

```
--- cmcbxti1.pps
+++ cmcbxti1.pps
@@ -730,29 +730,21 @@
    hsbw
    0 51 hstem
    635 51 hstem
-   34 4 callsubr
-   243 -21 rmoveto
-   13 0 6 12 6 9 rrcurveto
-   -42 hlineto
-   -1 0 -2 -1 hvcurveto
-   -10 8 -8 10 vhcurveto
-   closepath
-   35 4 callsubr
-   -227 21 rmoveto
-   53 0 53 3 53 0 rrcurveto
-   55 0 55 -3 56 0 rrcurveto
+   16 hmoveto
+   52 0 52 3 52 0 rrcurveto
+   54 0 54 -3 55 0 rrcurveto
    8 2 3 3 4 7 rrcurveto
    5 19 rlineto
    0 11 -6 6 -10 3 rrcurveto
-   -12 0 -13 0 -13 0 rrcurveto
-   342 450 rlineto
-   -112 -447 rlineto
+   -14 0 -16 0 -15 0 rrcurveto
+   359 444 rlineto
+   -110 -441 rlineto
    -30 -3 -37 0 -30 0 rrcurveto
    -8 -2 -4 -3 -3 -7 rrcurveto
    -5 -19 rlineto
    -9 5 -11 11 vhcurveto
-   53 0 53 3 53 0 rrcurveto
-   55 0 55 -3 56 0 rrcurveto
+   52 0 52 3 52 0 rrcurveto
+   54 0 54 -3 55 0 rrcurveto
    8 2 3 3 4 7 rrcurveto
    5 19 rlineto
    0 11 -6 6 -10 3 rrcurveto
@@ -762,20 +754,20 @@
    7 2 4 3 4 7 rrcurveto
    4 19 rlineto
    9 -5 11 -10 vhcurveto
-   -53 0 -53 -3 -53 0 rrcurveto
-   -56 0 -55 3 -55 0 rrcurveto
+   -52 0 -52 -3 -52 0 rrcurveto
+   -55 0 -54 3 -54 0 rrcurveto
    -8 -2 -4 -3 -3 -7 rrcurveto
    -5 -19 rlineto
    0 -11 6 -6 10 -3 rrcurveto
-   11 0 14 0 13 0 rrcurveto
-   -342 -450 rlineto
-   111 447 rlineto
+   14 0 16 0 15 0 rrcurveto
+   -360 -444 rlineto
+   110 441 rlineto
    30 3 37 0 31 0 rrcurveto
    7 2 4 3 4 7 rrcurveto
    4 19 rlineto
    9 -5 11 -10 vhcurveto
-   -53 0 -53 -3 -53 0 rrcurveto
-   -56 0 -55 3 -55 0 rrcurveto
+   -52 0 -52 -3 -52 0 rrcurveto
+   -55 0 -54 3 -54 0 rrcurveto
    -8 -2 -4 -3 -3 -7 rrcurveto
    -5 -19 rlineto
    0 -11 6 -6 10 -3 rrcurveto
@@ -786,13 +778,6 @@
    -5 -19 rlineto
    -9 5 -11 11 vhcurveto
    closepath
-   36 4 callsubr
-   655 686 rmoveto
-   43 hlineto
-   0 0 2 1 hvcurveto
-   10 -8 8 -10 vhcurveto
-   -12 0 -6 -12 -7 -9 rrcurveto
-   closepath
    endchar
    } |-
 /afii10024 {
```