# Resolution in tikz gradient

Tags: tikz-pgf, gradient

The issue: making a background gradient with tikz I had the following problem. The resolution of gradient is very low and hatched lines appear. (see an MWE + picture below)

The question: Is it possible to increase the resolution so that the gradient be smooth?

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fadings,through}

\definecolor{mydb} {RGB}{68,48,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [shading = axis,rectangle, left color=mydb, right color=mydb!30!white,shading angle=135, anchor=north, minimum width=45.5cm, minimum height=25.5cm, samples=2000] (box) at (10,25){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=210mm,minimum width=148.5mm,outer sep=0pt] (a)
{};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `latex` → `dvips` → `ps2pdf` by any chance? If so, I think you are out of luck because of how the shadings are constructed in Level 2 PostScript. If you are using `pdflatex`, then I think this is a viewer issue. It looks bad for me in some viewers (notably `acroread` 9), but good in `zathura` (`poppler` based viewer).

Comment: @David Purton  Using either `latex → dvips → ps2pdf`, either `pdflatex` I'm getting, more or less, the same result. I think that the interesting issue is the possibility of changing the resolution from tikz itself. I'm not sure whether this is possible or not.

Comment: You could change it for the `dvips` driver by rewriting the PostScript. But believe me, you don't want to do this unless you are crazy :). The `pdftex` driver uses a built in PDF function for the gradient. `tikz` does not have control over how it renders. Rather viewers decide how they will render the shading, so you get different output from different viewers. Banding effects are also increased when your two colours are very similar as there aren't as many colours to go in between.

Comment: Your other option is to render the gradient yourself to a bitmap using `ghostscript` and include the bitmap. This also gives a smooth gradient for me.

Comment: BTW, the `samples=2000` has no effect on your shading.

Comment: You could try adding this to your preamble. But I do not think it will make any difference: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\makeatletter\patchcmd{\pgfsys@vertshading}{/Domain}{/AntiAlias true\space/Domain}{}{}\makeatother`

Answer (score 3):

I use Asymptote adapted with [gkov's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129274/showcase-of-optical-illusions-made-with-tex-latex-luatex-context), and find that `axialshade` seems to be better than TikZ's `shade`.

[image]

```
size(210mm,148.5mm);
pen pena=RGB(68,48,0), penb=.3pena+.7white;
pair a=plain.SW, b=plain.NE;
axialshade(box((-2,-2),(2,2)), pena, 2a, penb, 2b);

//x.asy
// compiling F5 on texstudio on Windows 10
// Build "C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote/asy.exe" -f pdf -noView %.asy
// ImageMagick: magick -density 960 x.pdf x.png
```

Comment: This doesn't give better banding than `tikz` when I view it in `acroread`, which confirms my suspicion that this problem is basically a viewer issue.

Comment: Nevertheless, It would be very functional to have something analog to the option `samples` that we have for tikz-lines!

Comment: @GrigoriosKostakos, actually it wouldn't help much. With 8bit colour channels there isn't 2000 shades between your two colours anyway.